# Validar data como feriado ou não

Tags: python, pandas

Olá, boa tarde!
Estou criando um DataFrame em que eu preciso validar se um dia é feriado ou não, logo, criei uma time series na mão e fiz dois laços for para validar se a data que foi importada do csv e a data que inseri na mão são iguais, abaixo segue o código.

```
feriados = ['2015-01-01','2015-02-17','2015-04-03','2015-04-05','2015-04-21','2015-05-01','2015-06-04','2015-09-07',
        '2015-10-12','2015-11-02','2015-11-15','2015-12-25','2016-01-01','2016-02-09','2016-03-25','2016-03-27',
        '2016-04-21','2016-05-01','2016-05-26','2016-06-04','2016-09-07','2016-10-12','2016-11-02','2016-11-15',
        '2016-12-25','2017-01-01','2017-02-28','2017-04-14','2017-04-16','2017-04-21','2017-05-01','2017-05-26',
        '2017-06-15','2017-09-07','2017-10-12','2017-11-02','2017-11-15','2017-12-25','2018-01-01','2018-02-13',
        '2018-03-30','2018-04-01','2018-04-21','2018-05-01','2018-05-31','2018-09-07','2018-10-12','2018-11-02',
        '2018-11-15','2018-12-25','2019-01-01','2019-03-05','2019-04-19','2019-04-21','2019-05-01','2019-06-20',
        '2019-09-07','2019-10-12','2019-11-02','2019-11-15','2019-12-25']
feriados = pd.to_datetime(feriados, format='%Y-%m-%d')
feriados = pd.DataFrame({'data':feriados})

for dataD in dados['data']:
        for dataF in feriados['data']:
            if dataD == dataF:
                dados['feriado'] = 1
            else:
                dados['feriado'] = 0
```

Ai, quando eu vou conferir se ele setou alguma data como feriado, recebendo o valor 1 ele não me retorna nada. :/

```
dados.loc[dados.feriado == 1]
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Poderiam me ajudar?
Valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu pode fazer isso com a seguinte sequência:

- Unir os DataFrames com `merge` passando o comando **indicator =
  True**
- Verificar quais linhas estavam nos 2 Dataframes com    `np.where`
- Deletar a coluna extra criada pelo merge.

---

```
df= pd.merge(dados, feriados, how='left', on = 'data', indicator = True)
df['feriado'] = np.where(df['_merge'] == 'both', 1, 0)
df.drop('_merge', axis = 1, inplace= True)
```

Comment: Cara deu super certo, o passo 3 nem chega ser necessário porque depois que validei se a data é feriado ou não já tem grande grande valida no aprendizado de máquina. Obrigado, essa dica foi top!